# How to Log varnish cache key?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, varnish, varnish-vcl

```
sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.http.Host + req.url);
}
```

This is my varnish `vcl_hash` . Can someone enlighten me with configuration to log the cache key. so that I can verify what's the key being set.

I'm using varnish -6.6.1 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The built-in VCL behavior](https://%20https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnish-builtin-vcl/#4-vcl_hash) combines the URL and the `Host` header to compose the cache key. The implementation is slightly different from your example.

If you use a tool like `varnishlog` to inspect the Varnish logs, the cache key is not included in the output by default. You can unlock this using the [vsl_mask runtime parameter](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnishd.html#vsl-mask).

If you're only planning to temporarily visualize the hash, you can use the following command to enable it without persisting the setting:

```
varnishadm param.set vsl_mask +Hash
```

If you want to ensure the hash is always part of the VSL output, please edit your `varnishd` runtime configuration and add `-p vsl_mask=+Hash`.

Once the VSL mask is set, you can run the following command to test this:

```
varnishlog -g request -i requrl -I reqHeader:Host -i Hash
```

This command will return the logs for all transactions, but will only include the `ReqURL` tag, the `ReqHeader` tag for the `Host` header and the corresponding `Hash` tags.

Here's an example of what that could like like for `http://localhost/`:

```
*   << Request  >> 10
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqHeader      Host: localhost
-   Hash           "/%00"
-   Hash           "localhost%00"
```